# Wordpress admin menu post link missing

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, admin

I'm working on a client's WordPress website and I'm having getting the Posts tab back on the admin panel. It's missing in the page source and I'm not sure where it could have been removed from. I tried disabling plugins, I updated WordPress, I installed an admin menu control plugin and it shows all the other menu items but Posts is missing.

In the template functions.php there was an entry to hide it, I removed it and all others related. Comments was also hidden but reappeared when I did this.

Does anyone know where else the menu item could have been removed from or maybe how to restore it or the menu files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you post the functions.php entry it was removed with?

Comment: Here is the unmodified functions.php, line 599 has the function, basically I removed everything from 599 to 629: http://pastie.org/4252551

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what it was, a plugin (Magic Fields) had an option to hide the menu.